# How to map data coming from redux in react-native

Tags: mapping, react-native, react-native-ios, redux-saga

I have some data which is coming from api, I am able to save those data in redux. But I am not able to map those in UI.

Below is my code:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    createMenu = createMenuReducer.data;
    console.log("main: ",createMenu);
}, [createMenuReducer]);
```

Here all my data is getting logged in console.

Output in log:

```
main:  {}
main:  {}
main:  {cat1: Array(10), cat2: Array(10), cat3: Array(9), cat4: Array(10), cat5: Array(7), …}
```

Here I am trying to map those data in my UI:

```
const renderMenuCats = createMenu.map((menuCategory, index) => {
    return (
        <View key={index.toString()}>
            <View style={{ borderWidth: 0.5, paddingVertical: '4%' }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 5, color: 'grey' }}>Category {index.toString()}</Text>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
})
```

But I am getting error:

`Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong, and how to make this work.

**UPDATE**

Below is the updated code:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState();
React.useEffect(() => {
    setItems(createMenuReducer.data.product);
    console.log("item", items);
}, [items]);

<ScrollView>
    {createMenuReducer &&
        items?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <ItemComponent
                    item={item}
                />
            );
        })}
</ScrollView>
```

console.log output:

```
item undefined
```

but when I click save again then all  the items are getting consoled:

```
item (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I tried to update state, thinking it will also update the UI, but that is not happening. I am getting a blank page when loads first time, when when I click save again, all the items are shown in UI. How to fix this so that all the items are on the screen when the app loads??

Comment: your examples are a bit unclear and without context.
but first, `map` is not a property of an Object but of an Array. 
second try to: `const createMenu = createMenuReducer.data || {}`.
without the `useEfect` there is no need for that.

Comment: @AloneBashan It give error `createMenu.map` is not a function

Comment: true that is because `createMenu` is an `Object` and not an `Array`.
now the question is what you want to do with this object. 
I would use either `Object.keys(createMenu)` or `Object.values(createMenu)`,
depends if you want to get an array of the keys of the object `['cat1', 'cat2', ...]` or the values `[Array(10), Array(10), Array(9), ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

we have to use the redux value or state to update the UI at run time using the normal variables we cant update the UI of screen.

Comment: can you please give an example on how to do it?

Comment: can you show me the declaration of createMenu?

Comment: I have updated my post, please have a look

Comment: Have you tried to console.log(createMenuReducer.data.product) what value you are getting ?

Comment: Yes, it gives undefined when app is loaded first time. Second time it shows all the data

Comment: remove items dependency from useEffect

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when the component is initially loaded, the createMenu const is undefined/null. And you cannot map on undefined objects. So why don't you check if createMenu is undefined, and if so return null, else map through it.

Try something like this. Note the the **createMenu?.map** instead of **createMenu.map** before you map through it.

```
const renderMenuCats = createMenu?.map((menuCategory, index) => {
    return (
        <View key={index.toString()}>
            <View style={{ borderWidth: 0.5, paddingVertical: '4%' }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 5, color: 'grey' }}>Category {index.toString()}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
})
```

Comment: This does makes the error go away. But I want the data to be shown on screen, which is not happening

Comment: Are you reading data directly from the reducer? 
For redux to work properly, you should map state to props (through a connector) and thus get it inside the component rather than directly accessing it from the reducer.
[react-redux connect()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).
This connect() component is important and the component will listen to changes in redux store only when this is used

Comment: Also you can show a activity indicator initially when the items are empty or undefined and is being fetched. 
Something like
 `items||items?.length ? (<ScrollView>
    {createMenuReducer &&
        items?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <ItemComponent
                    item={item}
                />
            );
        })}
</ScrollView>)
: (<View style={{flex:1}}>
<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="blue"/>
</View>)`